# Navigation from one nav graph to other nav graph android

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have two activities : Main activity and Home activity

Main activity has following fragments : Login and onboarding and it has navGraph1

Home activity has three fragments with bottom navigation and it has navGraph2

Here is the flow of my app:

After login, if onBoarding is already done then open home activity. if onBoarding is not done, then navigate to onBoarding fragment. after onBoarding is complete then go to home activity.

[image: flow of app]

now how do I navigate from one nav graph to other? If I add a navGraph2 as nested graph in navGraph1 and add action then write findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_login_fragment_to_navGraph2), then the problem is that it is navigating to home fragment of navGraph2 but **bottom navigation bar is not showing up**.
Or do I have to make intent for home activity and launch it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with the navigation part.

Please double check where the bottom navigation is defined.
Is it really defined in the layout of the home fragment?
I guess you defined a activity which hold HomeFragment, FriendFragment, HistoryFragment. When I am right you have to refer this activity as destination.

Comment: I don't know why I never tried it :p
There is one more problem, on click of back button of **home activity**, I want to exit the app (not go back to activity 1), how to do this?
I have tried to set pop to  and enabled inclusive option in navigation but it's not working

Comment: Which destination id did you set there?

Comment: Destination : homeActivity, pop To : homeActivity, Inclusive:tried with both, true and false

Comment: And homeActivity is located in the nested graph_2, right? Is means when you go up you actually entering the parent graph again. Hopefully this is right! :) Can you try to make to popTo-thing to @id/graph_1?

Comment: This worked for me:
`<action
        android:id="@+id/to_auth"
        app:popUpTo="@id/main_navigation"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"
        app:destination="@id/auth_navigation"/>`

(main_navigation = root graph, auth_navigation = graph which handles the authentication)

Comment: but don't I have to add popUpTo and popUpToInclusive in my **auth_to_home** action? Because I use this action to go from activity 1 to activity 2 and on click of back on activity 2, I want to exit app

Comment: This is what I have tried based on your last comment, but it's still not working
`<action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashScreen_to_homeActivity"
            app:destination="@id/homeActivity"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_enter"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />`

Comment: I actually realizing now that you try to navigate between **activities**. Sorry but I was in the single activity world. Here (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate) you can read the following: _Note: If your app uses multiple activities, each activity uses a separate navigation graph. To take full advantage of the Navigation component, your app should use multiple fragments in a single activity........_ As I understand activities are total Independent in sense of the navigation component because they have separate navigation graphs.